# Trying to handle error codes for URL download

Tags: java, http

I am trying to download a page given an URL. However sometimes I get 403 error (Forbidden) or 404 error. I want to handle all these cases and get the html. 
Even if it is 404 I want to read the html contents. I am trying to handle cookies here but how to fix it for all sorts of error codes?

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    c.setRequestMethod("GET");

    c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    int responseCode = c.getResponseCode();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
```

Comment: *If* the server includes a body in the error response, which is not required and not always the case, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29 .

Comment: The is a close vote for your question, I would suggest to reformulate it to a "how to debug it" form, maybe it will heighten its chance to survive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want/need to respond to each possible **responseCode** on an individual basis, then after you close the InputStream you could try something like:

```
switch(responseCode)
{
  case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN:
  {
    someMethodToHandle403_Forbidden(response);
    break;
  }
  case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND:
  {
    someMethodToHandle404_NotFound(response);
    break;
  }
  case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAVAILABLE:
  {
    someMethodToHandle503_Unavailable(response);
    break;
  }
...
*...however many additional http response code cases you're going to handle...*
...
}
```

Comment: Sure that might help but I want to read HTML for all types of responses i.e. If I hit a URL on browser , even if gives 404 as response code , it still has some HTML and I want to read that HTML

Comment: You already have read the html --  it's in the StringBuffer named "response."

Comment: Yes however exception occurs at  "new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream())", java.io.FileNotFoundException. Hence I do not get anything in the "response"

Comment: Of which you made no mention when you originally posted the question.